# How do I tell the Jira API that I'm using an API token and not a password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

I try to authenticate to the Jira REST API with a token, but I get an error that `Basic authentication with passwords is deprecated`.
How do I tell the Jira API that I'm using Basic authentication with a token, not a password?

```
(venv) $ cat error_demo.py
import base64
import json
import requests

jira_user = 'me@myorg.com'
jira_token = '9rXXXXXXXXXX5B'

cred =  "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b"jira_user:jira_token").decode("utf-8")
print("cred =", cred)

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization" : cred
}

projectKey = "NETOP-1987"

url = "https://myorg.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=key=" + projectKey

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print("response =", response)
print("response.text =", response.text)

(venv) $ python error_demo.py
cred = Basic amYYYYYYYYYYYYYYW4=
response = <Response [401]>
response.text = Basic authentication with passwords is deprecated.  For more information, see: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/deprecation-notice-basic-auth/
```

Comment: have you tried to simply set `cred = jira_token`?

Comment: @walter
There are several issues with your suggestion: first, the token needs to be in base64 encoded as text, the Jira username needs to be included in the credentials, and the Authorisation needs to know that it is Basic (there are other authorisation possibilities).

Comment: if it's a token (that you should have obtained via OAuth), it's not Basic. It's either one or the other. Furthermore it shouldn't need encoding, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested that base64 is not needed for the credentials, but instead, the `HTTPBasicAuth` class from `requests.auth` should be used, and the resulting `auth` request object passed to the `headers` instead.

With that change, the script below returns the expected response:

```
import base64
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

jira_user = 'me@myorg.com'
jira_token = '9rXXXXXXXXXX5B'

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(jira_user, jira_token)
print("auth =", auth)

headers = {
"Accept": "application/json",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
}

projectKey = "NETOP-1987"

url = "https://myorg.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=key=" + projectKey

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, auth=auth)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(".", ": ")))
```

Comment: It seems to me that what you call a Jira token is actually a password. Basic authentication works with username and password. This is OK only as long as you are within your company's network, because the password can be decoded easily.

Comment: I forgot: ... and as long as you are using a service account (not your personal account)!

Comment: @WalterTross - Some Atlassian and other documentation call a Jira API token a "password", which is confusing.  In a Jira REST API call, an API token is used for when a password needs to be sent.